# How do I use AWS parameter store values in a MERN application?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, mern

I have built a MERN stack app that I am now attempting to launch on an EC2 instance. I initially had environment variables stored in a .env file for dev. I have transferred these values to AWS parameter store for added security in production. How do I import these values to code?

I have looked for resources online to guide me through the process. So far I have came across lots of posts and videos referring to lambda. Currently, my project does not use lambda. Is this something I should dig deeper into?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can import your stored variables using the `aws-sdk` as shown in this article: https://notificare.com/blog/2021/02/12/Using-Parameter-Store-With-Node/.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.